# checking bootstrap toggle button state using selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have below html

```
    <div id="Show">
       <label style="width: 150px">Show options</label>
       <div class="toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="toggle" data-bind="toggle:mySettings().ShowMe, css:{off:!mySettings().ShowMe()}">
          <div class="toggle-group">
                <label class="btn btn-primary toggle-on">ON</label>
                <label class="btn btn-default active toggle-off">OFF</label>
                <span class="toggle-handle btn btn-default"></span>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to see if button is on or off. If it is on then i want to make it off and viceversa. So i tried below code to turn on

```
var statusOfButton = WebDriver.WaitFor(
            ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//label[@class='btn btn-primary toggle-on']")),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));



        if (!statusOfButton.Selected)
        {
           var offButtonElement =  WebDriver.WaitFor(
                ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//label[@class='toggle btn btn-default off']")),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
           offButtonElement.Click();


        }
```

This worked for first instance when test ran. Initially button was off so it made it on. Next time when test ran the button was on and then i got error on this line saying no such element found.

```
         var offButtonElement =  WebDriver.WaitFor(
                ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//label[@class='toggle btn btn-default off']")),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector for the off button seems to be broken.

There is no *off* class on the button but a *toggle-off*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your classes don't match classes provided in Your XPath. 
By the way if You want to find element containing some classes You should use `label[contains(@class, 'your-classses here')]`